# Access Express res.render locals in <script> WITHOUT data being visible in source?

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I've been doing this to access variables passed to the EJS template via Express's res.render:

```js
router.route("/build")
.get([isLoggedIn, finishedRegistration], function(req, res){
    res.render("build", {loggedInUser: req.loggedInUser});
})
```

And then utilizing them on the client side within script tags as needed:

```js
<script>
    var user = <%- JSON.stringify(loggedInUser) %>
  //do something with stringified variable
  //do another thing with it
</script>
```

This solution is given in many Stackoverflow questions, and it works fine, but if you peek at the source code in the browser...

```js
<script>

    var user = {"tokens":-3,"_id":"615c62ba5d2315162893a4ac","username":"dev","email":"shg.webdev... (and so on)
```

Oops, everybody and their dog can see the data being stringified. This seems vulnerable to me. Is there an alternative way that doesn't expose data like that? Or, can I hide the stringified data from being seen in the source?

Comment: All client-side JS is always visible to the user, period. Sending sensitive data to the client is either a) not necessary, because a user is logged in and anything sensitive happens on the server or b) no problem, because the user is logged in and only they will see their sensitive data. So "everybody and their dog can see the data being stringified" is not exactly right, it's: "everybody and their dog can see **their own** data being stringified" (also, ejs is garbage, use [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) instead)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!